# How to connect to OpenStack instance (Ubuntu LXD Single Machine setup with conjure-up)

Tags: networking, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I installed Openstack on a single machine on Ubuntu 16.04 following the instructions from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/try-openstack. I found the LXD IP for Horizon and I'm able to create instances. I assigned a subnet to ext-net (10.200.1.0/24) and added a floating ip to the instance (10.200.1.5). The instance has also the default ubuntu-net network (10.101.0.0/24) and an ip (10.101.0.3) from that network. Everything seems to be alright except that I'm unable to connect/ping the created instance. I figured out in which lxd container the instance was created and tried to ping from there, i tried to added static routes to the network to lxdbr0 (which was created during lxd installation) as well as conjureup0 (which was created during the openstack installation) but nothing helped. Any hints what I did wrong and what I need to do to access the instance?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the vm through the private IP you can do that though the router namespace.
In the controller:

```
# ip netns ls
...
qrouter-xxx
...
# ip netns exec qrouter-xxx bash
# ping 10.101.0.3
```

In order to access trough the floating IP you will need a valid route.